# How to find rows of list items with a key-search element in pandas?

Tags: pandas, string, list, dataframe, search

I have a pandas dataframe with lists. I want to be able to search using one item in the list. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list elements
data = [[10, ["a", "b", "c"] ], [20, ["d", "e", "f"]], [30, ["c"]]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers', "Characters"])
  
# print data
df

Numbers     Characters_List
0   10  [a, b, c]
1   20  [d, e, f]
2   30  ["c"]
```

If I search for "e", the output should be,

```
Numbers     Characters_List
0   20  [d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: "e" in x.Characters, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked. If I may ask, can you explain the use of axis = 1 here?

Comment: @Droid-Bird sure `axis=1` means `apply` lambda function for each row not each column (default, axis=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df['Characters'].explode()=='e'
df.loc[s[s].index]
```

**Result**

```
  Numbers Characters
1      20  [d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
serachCharacter='e'

df[df['Characters'].apply(lambda x:len(set(x).intersection(set(f'{serachCharacter}')))>0)]

   Numbers Characters
1       20  [d, e, f]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.